# Show checkboxes on table column header with angular material

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I try to make some checkboxes on the table header column with data from the backend.

So if you hover over the table header then you will see the checkboxes under the title of the header column.

I only found a solution for the row-column, but not for the header column.

So I try it to do it like this:

```html
<ng-container matColumnDef="projects">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header i18n>
    Projects
    <mat-checkbox
      [style.opacity]="row.show || selection.isSelected(row) ? 100 : 0"
      (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
      (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
      [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
    >
    </mat-checkbox>
  </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">{{row.projects}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

And the CSS:

```css
.mat-header-cell mat-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
.mat-header-cell:hover mat-checkbox {
  display: block;
}
```

And the component code:

```js
export class ListComponent {
  datasource = new MatTableDataSource<ParticipantInfoDTO>(this.participantInfo);


  addShowCheckboxProperty() {
    this.participantInfo.map((data: any) => {
      data.show = false
    });
  }

  handleMouseOver(column) {
    const position = column.position;
    this.participantInfo.map((data: any) => {
      if (data.position === position) {
        data.show = true;
      }
    });
  }

  handleMouseLeave(column) {
    const position = column.position;
    this.participantInfo.map((data: any) => {
      if (data.position === position) {
        data.show = false;
      }
    });
  }
  // ...
}
```

But I get some errors like this:

```
ListComponent.html:82 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ListComponent.html:4)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:20458)
```

I'm not sure as to how to fix this issue.

Comment: for what purpose would you like to show a checkbox inside the column header ?

Comment: It is for filtering. Show then the names of the projects has to be visible. A user can then select a project name and the results will been shown then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not simply using an auxiliar array: `selection:bool[]=[]` and a variable `show`?

Your columns becomes like

```
<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef 
          (mouseover)="show=true" 
          (mouseout)="show=false"><mat-checkbox
          [style.opacity]="show ? 1 : 0"
          (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
          (change)="selection[0]=$event.isChecked" //or selection[1], or selection[2]..
          [checked]="selection[0]" //or selection[1], or selection[2]..
          ></mat-checkbox>No</th>
```

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hgatze?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftable-basic-example.html)